# Console.log() and el.innerText reset immidiately (help)

Tags: javascript, dom, console, console.log

I have this simple template in a html file. Every time I click the button it should log the click event and print '[NodeList]' in the #result element but it doesn't. In fact it prints it for miliseconds and then removes it again. Same thing with console.log(e). I have recorded this behaviour:
Link to video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B7TycQxZPi0dqx7Try6kUZM3pcJs0ILW/view

Can anybody suggest a fix?

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", e => {
  console.log(e);
  result.innerText = document.getElementsByName("day");
});
```

```html
<h1>Your Day Plan:</h1>
<p>Enter your day</p>
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="mon" name="day" value="mon" />
  <label for="mon">mon</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="tue" name="day" value="tue" />
  <label for="tue">tue</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="wed" name="day" value="wed" />
  <label for="wed">wed</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="thu" name="day" value="thu" />
  <label for="thu">thu</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="fri" name="day" value="fri" />
  <label for="fri">fri</label><br />
  <button id="btn">Calculate Plan</button>
</form>
<h5 id="result"></h5>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default type of button is submit, to prevent the form submission you have to specify the `type="button"` manually:

```
<button type="button" id="btn">Calculate Plan</button>
```

**OR:** use [**event.preventDefault()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

> The *Event* interface's `preventDefault()` method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

```html
<h1>Your Day Plan:</h1>
<p>Enter your day</p>
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="mon" name="day" value="mon" />
  <label for="mon">mon</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="tue" name="day" value="tue" />
  <label for="tue">tue</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="wed" name="day" value="wed" />
  <label for="wed">wed</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="thu" name="day" value="thu" />
  <label for="thu">thu</label><br />
  <input type="radio" id="fri" name="day" value="fri" />
  <label for="fri">fri</label><br />
  <button id="btn">Calculate Plan</button>
</form>
<h5 id="result"></h5>

<script>

  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log(e);
    result.innerText = document.getElementsByName("day");
    event.preventDefault();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: or use `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much. Not really experienced